# Fiddle works but test page doesn't (missing .ready handler)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, I want to show some specific field when i select a specific radio button. I did that and I test on this page (http://jsfiddle.net/niklakis/cw0qLnk5/5/)  but when i get the code (which is the below) it does not show the specific fields when I select the radio button.
Can you help me please?

THIS IS THE WHOLE CODE ....

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == "Doctor") {
            $("#DoctorRegister").show();
        } else {
            $("#DoctorRegister").hide();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Patient") {
            $("#PatientGM").show();
            $("#PatientGF").show();
            $("#PatientAge").show();
            $("#SelectDisease").show();
            $("#Male").show();
            $("#Female").show();
            $("#Age").show();
            $("#Disease").show();
        } else {
            $("#PatientGM").hide();
            $("#PatientGF").hide();
            $("#PatientAge").hide();
            $("#SelectDisease").hide();
            $("#Male").hide();
            $("#Female").hide();
            $("#Age").hide();
            $("#Disease").hide();
        }

    });</script>


    </head> 
    <body>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <label>First Name
            <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Last Name
            <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Username
            <input type="text" name="username" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Email
            <input type="text" name="email" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Password
            <input type="text" name="password" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
        User Type:
        <br/>
        Doctor <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Doctor" />
        Patient <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Patient" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="DoctorRegister" id="DoctorRegister" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label style="display:none;" id="Male">Male</label>
        <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="PatientGM" value="male" id="PatientGM">

        <label style="display:none;" id="Female">Female</label>
        <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="PatientGF" value="male" id="PatientGF">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label style="display:none;" id="Age">Age:</label>
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="PatientAge" id="PatientAge" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label style="display:none;" id="Disease">Disease:</label>
        <select style="display:none;" id="SelectDisease">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
      </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _jQuery does not work properly_ I doubt the issue is with jQuery, but I'd believe __your script__ doesn't work properly.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work just fine in my browser...

Comment: so whats the actual problem? what fields are not showing? it seems to be doing something in your fiddle so what about that is wrong?

Comment: @jmore009 can you send me a print screen of the result while you select the Patient Radio Button in order to confirmed what you said and if you are right then i need to find a way to fix it on my pc

Comment: @Mathletics i have this <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, you've got the change event tied to radio buttons which will cause all kinds of issues when trying to click the radio buttons for Male Female which display when doctor is shown ... weird toggle.

Comment: I cant post an image in comments, i see: Male/Female (radio btns), Age (text field), Disease (select field)

Comment: No need to request a print screen...the code itself works fine when executed properly within a load handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing your code before the document is rendered. Either:

1. Move your code to the end of the document before the closing body tag or
2. Put your code in a [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler in the head like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9qzhgzaz/)**

Comment: thank you i did with ur first option and it works, but now i realise that i have another problem, when i clicked on patient button and then i clicked on the one of the gender options it disappears the the rest of the patients' fields , can you help me with that ?

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to change the selector from `$("input[type='radio']")` to `$("input[name='answer']")`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9qzhgzaz/1/

Comment: problem number 2 .. if you select Male and then you decide to select Female it keeps both of the choices and it doesn't unchecked the other one. I checked my code and still can't find the solution.
Can you help me?

Comment: The radio button groups need the same name, but different values. That's the way the work.

Comment: my friend you are so good and I am afraid to ask your help for my next problem because I already spam you with looooot of questions

Comment: my friend can you take a look on this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642121/result-of-the-radio-buttons-does-not-work-properly-if-i-have-the-code-for-both-o)

Answer (score 1):

`$("input[type='radio']").change()` will fire for all inputs of type radio button. So, try with:

`$("input[type='radio'][name='answer']").change()`