# Result of the radio buttons does not work properly if I have the code for both of the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, i have two radio buttons which if you select on the Doctor radio button it will display all the next fields which are needed to show for the doctors and the same we want to happen if you select the patient radio button , i did it to work fine if I have the code for the patient for example but if i write the code also for the doctor it destroy the result of the both options 
HERE IS THE CODE...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <label>First Name
        <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Last Name
        <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Username
        <input type="text" name="username" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Email
        <input type="text" name="email" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Password
        <input type="text" name="password" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br/><br/>
 User Type:
<br/>
Doctor <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Doctor" />
Patient <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Patient" />
<br/>
<br/>
<!--DOCTOR OPTIONS 

<label style="display:none;" id="Male">Male</label>
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorGM">

<label style="display:none;" id="Female">Female</label>
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorGF">
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="Age">Age:</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="DoctorAge" id="DoctorAge" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="Specialty">Specialty:</label>
<select style="display:none;" id="SelectSpecialty">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="ID">Doctor ID:</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="Doctor_ID" id="Doctor_ID" />
-->

<!--PATIENT OPTIONS -->
<label style="display:none;" id="Male">Male</label>
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="PatientGender" value="male" id="PatientGM">

<label style="display:none;" id="Female">Female</label>
    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="PatientGender" value="male" id="PatientGF">
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="Age">Age:</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="PatientAge" id="PatientAge" />
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="Disease">Disease:</label>
<select style="display:none;" id="SelectDisease">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<label style="display:none;" id="SPID">SPID:</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="PatientSPID" id="PatientSPID" />
</fieldset>
</body>
<script>
$("input[type='radio'][name='answer']").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "Doctor") {
        $("#DoctorGM").show();
        $("#DoctorGF").show();
        $("#DoctorAge").show();
        $("#SelectSpecialty").show();
        $("#Male").show();
        $("#Female").show();
        $("#Age").show();
        $("#Disease").show();
        $("#ID").show();
        $("#Doctor_ID").show();
    } else {
        $("#PatientGM").hide();
        $("#PatientGF").hide();
        $("#PatientAge").hide();
        $("#SelectDisease").hide();
        $("#Male").hide();
        $("#Female").hide();
        $("#Age").hide();
        $("#Disease").hide();
        $("#ID").hide();
        $("#Doctor_ID").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Patient") {
        $("#PatientGM").show();
        $("#PatientGF").show();
        $("#PatientAge").show();
        $("#SelectDisease").show();
        $("#Male").show();
        $("#Female").show();
        $("#Age").show();
        $("#Disease").show();
        $("#SPID").show();
        $("#PatientSPID").show();
    } else {
        $("#PatientGM").hide();
        $("#PatientGF").hide();
        $("#PatientAge").hide();
        $("#SelectDisease").hide();
        $("#Male").hide();
        $("#Female").hide();
        $("#Age").hide();
        $("#Disease").hide();
        $("#SPID").hide();
        $("#PatientSPID").hide();
    }

});</script>
</html>
```

PS 1: I COMMENTED THE CODE FOR THE DOCTOR IN ORDER TO WORK PROPERLY FOR THE PATIENT
PS 2: http://jsfiddle.net/niklakis/qp7s409a/24/ HERE IS A LINK TO SEE WHAT HAPPENS IF A HAVE BOTH OF THE CODE

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can you explain it again? Also, the jsfiddle works -- both of the sections appear properly when you click the radios. :)

Comment: @Purag this how it look if a have only the patient options code (http://prntscr.com/5kls90) and this is how it looks with both code for the patient and doctor options (http://prntscr.com/5klsrb)

Comment: okay, I think I get it, some of the inputs aren't displaying properly, right?

Comment: @Purag can you find any solution my friend because i cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can edit the HTML of this form, you should put the extra fields inside separate `div`s and hide just those divs. Then, your jQuery becomes much simpler, too.

Now in this jQuery, what we're doing is hiding both of the "expansion" sections by default. That's the line `$("[id^=expand]").hide()`. What this does is select all elements whose `id` starts with `expand` and hides them.

Then, we select the expansion section associated with the clicked radio and show that.

```js
$("input[type='radio'][name='answer']").change(function() {
  $("[id^=expand]").hide();
  $("#expand" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  User Type:
  <br/>Doctor
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Doctor" />
  Patient
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Patient" />

  <!--DOCTOR OPTIONS -->
  <div id="expandDoctor" style="display:none;">
    <label id="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorG">
    <label id="Female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorG">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="DoctorAge" id="DoctorAge" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Specialty">Specialty:</label>
    <select id="SelectSpecialty">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="ID">Doctor ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Doctor_ID" id="Doctor_ID" />
  </div>

  <!--PATIENT OPTIONS -->
  <div id="expandPatient" style="display:none;">
    <label id="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="male" id="PatientGM">
    <label id="Female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="male" id="PatientGF">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="PatientAge" id="PatientAge" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Disease">Disease:</label>
    <select id="SelectDisease">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="SPID">SPID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="PatientSPID" id="PatientSPID" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

However, you were having your problem because you were trying to show and hide elements that weren't actually there. For example, you were trying to show/hide `#DoctorGM`, which doesn't exist, you only have `#DoctorG`. You should change those `id`s, too, because it's invalid to have any elements sharing the same `id` in HTML.

Comment: first of all I want to say sorry for spamming you but how i can have an if statement which if it is selected from the radio buttons doctor or patient it will send the data in the appropriate table of the database(doctor or patient). I am using php and mysql, can you help me PLEASE with this problem

Comment: @NickBourlai Not a problem! So you are sending the form data to a php file, correct?

Comment: yes, to be more specific this will be my registration form so I want to get all these data and when they select if they are doctor or patient to get the appropriate data and send it to the specific table of the database.

PS: if there is a way to send you a private message please inform and i will give you my email address to send you all my files for the registration form

Comment: in your PHP file, you just need to have an if that checks what `$_POST["answer"]` is. If it's `Doctor`, then add it to the doctor table. if it's patient, add it to the patient table.

Comment: something like that...
$fname = sanitizeString($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = sanitizeString($_POST['lname']);
    $username = sanitizeString($_POST['username']);
    $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
    $password = sanitizeString($_POST['password']);
    if($_POST["answer"])
    {
        $DoctorG = sanitizeString($_POST['DoctorG']);
        $DoctorAge = ($_POST['DoctorAge']);
        $specialty = sanitizeString($_POST['specialty']);
        $Doctor_ID = ($_POST['Doctor_ID']);

Comment: here is a link with all my code http://jsfiddle.net/niklakis/k4hvvmh6/ also why y have 3 === and not 2 == , are you sure that we need three ? sry for the silly question

Comment: @NickBourlai it'll be better if you ask a new question. ;)

Comment: here is the link of the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643068/insert-data-from-a-registration-form