# Insert Data from a dynamic registration form with radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data to my database from a form and when i select a type (doctor or patient) to send the data to the appropriate table.

HERE IS THE CODE

```
    <?php



    include_once 'header.php';


    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) destroySession();
    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $fname = sanitizeString($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = sanitizeString($_POST['lname']);
        $username = sanitizeString($_POST['username']);
        $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
        $password = sanitizeString($_POST['password']);
        if($_POST["answer" === "Doctor"])
        {
            $DoctorG = sanitizeString($_POST['DoctorG']);
            $DoctorAge = ($_POST['DoctorAge']);
            $specialty = sanitizeString($_POST['specialty']);
            $Doctor_ID = ($_POST['Doctor_ID']);

                 if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM doctor
                      WHERE username='$username'")))
                    $error = "That username already exists<br /><br />";
                else
                  {
                    queryMysql("INSERT INTO doctor (fname,lname,username,email,password,gender,age,specialty,doctorID) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email', '$password','$DoctorG','$DoctorAge','$specialty','$DoctorID')");
                    die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.<br /><br />");
                  }
        }




    }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="signup.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <label>First Name
        <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Last Name
        <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Username
        <input type="text" name="username" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Email
        <input type="text" name="email" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label>Password
        <input type="text" name="password" required="required" />
    </label>
    <br/><br/>
 User Type:
  <br/>Doctor
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Doctor" />
  Patient
  <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Patient" />

  <!--DOCTOR OPTIONS -->
  <div id="expandDoctor" style="display:none;">
    <label id="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorG">
    <label id="Female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="female" id="DoctorG">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="DoctorAge" id="DoctorAge" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Specialty">Specialty:</label>
    <select id="SelectSpecialty" name="specialty">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="ID">Doctor ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Doctor_ID" id="Doctor_ID" />
  </div>

  <!--PATIENT OPTIONS -->
  <div id="expandPatient" style="display:none;">
    <label id="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="male" id="PatientGM">
    <label id="Female">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="female" id="PatientGF">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Age">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="PatientAge" id="PatientAge" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="Disease">Disease:</label>
    <select id="SelectDisease" name="specialty">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label id="SPID">SPID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="PatientSPID" id="PatientSPID" />
  </div>
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>
$("input[type='radio'][name='answer']").change(function() {
  $("[id^=expand]").hide();
  $("#expand" + $(this).val()).show();
});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\xampp\htdocs\ptixiaki\signup.php on line 21

PS: I dont have all the needed inserts , I just want to test it for the Doctor and if it works for them I will do for the patient also

Comment: What is the question? First thing I noticed; no form tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i added the tags thanks, and the question is that i have a dynamic form which means that when the user selects if he is a patient of a doctor from the radio buttons to get that value and send the data to the appropriate table of the databse. And I am not sure if this code do that

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` then, or whatever method you're using to query with; seeing it's custom function.

Comment: You have an "answer" below; you can deal with that person. How some are quick to react and post answers without asking questions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i should have if( $_POST["answer"] === "Doctor" ) instead of if($_POST["answer" === "Doctor"]) and then it shows a second error in the INSERT INTO which was an underscore in the Doctor_ID

HERE IS THE NEW CODE....

```
 <?php

    /**
     * @author Nick Bourlai
     * @copyright 2014
     */

    include_once 'header.php';


    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) destroySession();
    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $fname = sanitizeString($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = sanitizeString($_POST['lname']);
        $username = sanitizeString($_POST['username']);
        $email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
        $password = sanitizeString($_POST['password']);
        if( $_POST["answer"] === "Doctor" )
        {
            $DoctorG = sanitizeString($_POST['DoctorG']);
            $DoctorAge = ($_POST['DoctorAge']);
            $specialty = sanitizeString($_POST['specialty']);
            $Doctor_ID = ($_POST['Doctor_ID']);

                 if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM doctor
                      WHERE username='$username'")))
                    $error = "That username already exists<br /><br />";
                else
                  {
                    queryMysql("INSERT INTO doctor (fname,lname,username,email,password,gender,age,specialty,doctorID) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email', '$password','$DoctorG','$DoctorAge','$specialty','$Doctor_ID')");
                    die("<h4>Account created</h4>Please Log in.<br /><br />");
                  }
        }




    }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="signup.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <label>First Name
            <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Last Name
            <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Username
            <input type="text" name="username" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Email
            <input type="text" name="email" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Password
            <input type="text" name="password" required="required" />
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
     User Type:
      <br/>Doctor
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Doctor" />
      Patient
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Patient" />

      <!--DOCTOR OPTIONS -->
      <div id="expandDoctor" style="display:none;">
        <label id="Male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="male" id="DoctorG">
        <label id="Female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="DoctorG" value="female" id="DoctorG">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="Age">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="DoctorAge" id="DoctorAge" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="Specialty">Specialty:</label>
        <select id="SelectSpecialty" name="specialty">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="ID">Doctor ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Doctor_ID" id="Doctor_ID" />
      </div>

      <!--PATIENT OPTIONS -->
      <div id="expandPatient" style="display:none;">
        <label id="Male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="male" id="PatientGM">
        <label id="Female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="PatientG" value="female" id="PatientGF">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="Age">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="PatientAge" id="PatientAge" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="Disease">Disease:</label>
        <select id="SelectDisease" name="specialty">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
          <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label id="SPID">SPID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="PatientSPID" id="PatientSPID" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    <script>
    $("input[type='radio'][name='answer']").change(function() {
      $("[id^=expand]").hide();
      $("#expand" + $(this).val()).show();
    });</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```